# How can I disable evil in help-mode?

Tags: evil, help-mode

I have the following in my `init.el`, and it does a great job of automatically disabling evil in certain emacs modes:

```
(dolist (mode '(git-rebase-mode
        flycheck-error-list-mode
        inf-ruby-mode
        term-mode))
  (add-to-list 'evil-emacs-state-modes mode))
```

However, this will not work for `help-mode`, which is frustrating, as `help-mode` has some great keybindings I'd like to take advantage of. I've also tried this: `(add-to-list 'evil-emacs-state-modes 'help-mode)`, but it didn't work either.

How can I turn off evil in `help-mode`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason this fails is because `help-mode` is in `evil-motion-state-modes` by default, adding it to `evil-emacs-state-modes` will therefore not have the desired effect as Evil looks it up in `evil-motion-state-modes` first to determine the initial state.

The correct way to change the initial state of a mode is by using `evil-set-initial-state`:

```
(evil-set-initial-state 'help-mode 'emacs)
```

This helper function ensures that a given mode cannot be in more than one of the `evil-*-state-modes` variables.  Alternatively customize every initial state variable to hold the correct modes and make sure you're not introducing any duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem and taught me more about emacs lisp functions.